# Which regex could match those values?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm developing new specific syntax. Within it there are two kinds of code:

**I**: `=` or `+` or `-` (one or several plus, minus or equal signs in a row);

Regex for that is `/[+=-]+/`.

**II**: `6:+` or `15:-` or `999:=` (any integer, followed by one plus, minus or equal sign);

Regex for that is `/\d+:[+=-]/`.

In one entry there may be any amount of any of these tokens.
Each new entry has to be surrounded by brackets: `[code here]`.
Kinds of code in brackets may stand next to each other:   `[=6:+-]` or `[15:-++=3:+]` etc.
Empty entries are not allowed.

So, I can't make a regex to match proper entries!
I've tried this one `/\[([=+-]*(\d+:[=+-])?[=+-]*)\]/`, but it matches `[]` as well, while it is an еггог.

---

**MATCH** *any of those*

```
[=]     [---]       [+=-]       [=+-]       [17:=]      [==+-]      [6:=-]      [+5:=-]

[==-=+] [+=====-]  [15:-++=3:+] [=======]   [+=-+==-]   [---==--]   [==-=+==]   [=--==--]
```

**NO MATCH**

```
[]  [=:1]   [:2+]   [3-:]
```

Comment: Regex in what environment / language / tool? The syntax varies.

Comment: @TomZych: I use Sublime Text for the time being without any compiler / interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, it could be **way** more simple:

```
\[(?:(?:\d+:)?[+=-])+\]
```

[image]

I can't believe I was so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what flavor of regex but this should work for pretty much all of them:

```
\[((?:[+=-]+|[+=-]?\d+:[+=-]+)+)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ERkzfl31uXYXA2wj)

It makes use of `|` or operand, so it either captures one kind of match (the collection of `-+=` signs or the numbers with colons and such)

Also, it seems that since you want `[+5:=-]` to match, I added a `[+-]?` to match for that.

EDIT:
This allows for multiple occurrences of the language. This, however, may be trivial as there is nothing to distinguish between separate parts of code.

Comment: It may be `[+5:=-]` or `[-5:=-]` or `[=5:=-]`.

Comment: then just add the `=` sign in those brackets and you should be good as good. also, I changed the `[+=-]` to have a `+` token

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with such a complex entries as `[+=-5:=-6:=-]`. But it is good in simple ones.

Comment: ah I didnt know you wanted more complex ones. I will try to make it work, an extra `+` token should work, I will edit